# Where should my users permissions live?

Tags: api-design, permissions, users

I'm building an application that allows the creation of users. These users can have profiles which define their permissions, as well as be given specific permissions.

Now I'm struggling on deciding where these permissions should be stored.

Of course they will be stored in a database, but when a user makes an API request, I don't want to query the database every time to check what permissions they have. I could put a cache in front of the database, but I'd still be querying the database every time.

I've been debating putting the permissions directly in the access token. This way, I can validate their permission on every request, without querying the database. However, if the user has a bunch of permissions, then the access token will get significantly long. Is there a risk that it can be too long?

I'm just struggling to understand the industry standard and best practices for validating permissions for a user.

Comment: *"I don't want to query the database every time to check what permissions they have"* - why not?

Answer (score 8):

My advice is use the database. Don't solve a problem you don't know for sure you have. And don't underestimate the kind of load a well tuned database can handle. Generally permissions involve looking up unique user id's, which can be very fast if everything is properly indexed. If you eventually encounter speed problems, then its time to start investigating caching solutions. But until then, no reason to  make things more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 3):

The argument against using databases for permissions is usually one of performance - the need to do additional database hits.

There are a least two good reasons to use database based permissions:

- When the permissions are data/row specific - you can only really store the permissions in the DB in this case (at least it would be complex to store them elsewhere).
- Before performance becomes an issue - i.e. the permissions check probably only represents a small overhead and caching may be a valid option (depending upon your access patterns).

However if performance does become an issue, there are several techniques to mitigate the cost:

**Common Permissions**

In many systems there is a "basic user" that performs a basic set of actions a majority of the time - such actions represent a significant percentage of the total requests to the system - hence if you include such a "basic" permission in the access token, a large percentage of your requests can be serviced without needing to check the database, i.e. you can still check the DB for the uncommon requests.

**Denial of Service Protection**

If you have a mechanism to quickly check the validity of tokens (authorized/not authorized) you can drop invalid requests on the edge of your infrastructure - additionally you may be able to use the identity of such tokens to automatically block bad actors.

**Internal vs External Tokens**

If the concern is the size of the token as they traverse the internet, another option is to do the permissions check once on the edge of your infrastructure and replace the external token with an internal one that has the additional permissions. This has the benefits of only doing the permission check once even if multiple internal services are needed to service the external request and since the check is repeated every time a new external request is made, changes in permissions can be applied quickly without having to invalidate multiple caches.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a risk that the token will get too long. There is no point in putting every permission in the token unless you know that the permissions will be a fixed, manageable size. You will also need to sign the token on the server side cryptographically so that you can ensure that it hasn't been tampered with.

There's nothing wrong with storing the permissions in a cache like Redis or memcache and querying that on every request. That's what these systems are for. Without knowing your performance needs, it's difficult to provide more detailed guidance.

It's also important to know how often the permissions will change, since that will affect cache behaviour significantly.